# Installing a boot service on Android

Tags: android, boot

My Android app needs to start when the device boots up. I used ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED with a Broadcast Receiver to handle this. However, Google has placed a limitation on this. If the app is installed on an SD card, the Broadcast Receiver will not receive the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED message. They must be installed on internal memory to start at boot time. That really sucks. Some devices simply don't ship with enough internal memory. Hopefully Google implements a way to install boot apps on SD cards.

In the meantime, is there any other workaround where I can get my app to boot but have it installed on the SD card?

Comment: Suggestion: You can create an application which simply start your application from SD card on device boot. Now put this application in to device's internal memory.

Comment: But then users would be required to download and install two apps? How can I prevent that?

Comment: Search for how to install application from another application.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the real problem-  at the time BOOT_COMPLETE is sent, the SD card is not yet mounted.  If you were to call getExternalStorageDir in a receiver it would actually fail-  it can't read the drive yet.  Unless they decide to do that (which would greatly slow down the boot complete event), they can't make it work for SD card apps.

You could build a boot loader type app that goes on the internal storage, waits for external storage to be mounted, then runs your app by starting your service/activity, as @Lucifer suggested.  Its your best bet.

Comment: Android shouldn't be issuing the BOOT_COMPLETE message until AFTER all hardware has been completed. This is just plain idiotic programming from amateur developers at Google.

Answer (score 0):

This app, available in Google Play can be used to start the app on boot:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.niwota.start